# zsh, how to limit FILE completion to current directory only (like bash)

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

Let's first see what bash does:

I am in a directory with only 1 file in it:

```
(bme) me@test_399_zsh_comp$ tree
.
└── common.sh

0 directories, 1 file
(bme) me@test_399_zsh_comp$
```

Now if I type `source co` and tab, bash only has `common.sh` and uses it.

`$ source co` (tab) => `source common.sh`

whereas zsh "helpfully" wants to bring in files (not commands) found elsewhere.

`test_399_zsh_comp % source co`

(tab)

```
test_399_zsh_comp % source co
code@                  comm*                  compress*              convertfilestops*      corelist-5.28*
code2flow@             command*               compression_tool*      convertformat*         corelist-5.30*
codesign*              common.sh              config_data*           convertsegfilestopdf*  corelist5.18*
codesign_allocate*     common.vuepress.sh     config_data5.30*       convertsegfilestops*   corelist5.30*
col*                   commonize@             configurations/        converttopdf*          coverage*
colcrt*                compare*               conjure*               converttops*           coverage-3.10*
colldef*               compare.txt            convert*               cookiecutter*          coverage3*
colrm*                 compile_et*            convert-keyring*       coreaudiod*            
column*                composite*             convertfilestopdf*     corelist@
```

Is there a way to bring completions more in line with bash?  Specifically, I don't want to look for files outside the current directory.

Strangely enough, `ls` behaves more like what I want under zsh, completing to just `common.sh`.  Is there something particular to keep in mind between `ls` and `source` argument completion under zsh?

`ls co` (tab) => `ls common.sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The completion system is searching the `PATH` to find matching scripts and files for the `source` command. The completion for `ls` doesn't use `PATH` since that wouldn't make sense - that's why you're seeing different results there.

A couple of ways to change the behavior:

###### Option 1

Prefix the filename with `./`:

`source ./co` <kbd>tab</kbd>

This will bypass the path search, so it's only going to find files in the current directory. It's also a useful habit in many other contexts and can have some security benefits.

It will also work with `.`, the shorter form of the command:

`. ./co` <kbd>tab</kbd>

###### Option 2

Remove the specific completion for the `source` command. One way is to add this line to `~/.zshrc`, somewhere after any other completion setup (e.g. a call to `compinit`):

`unset '_comps[source]'`

Now completion will fall back to the default version, which does not use the path.

Comment: #2 worked like a charm (I was aware of #1 but really wanted back to bash style completions for this).  Sorry I took so long to test this, it was really a small edge case in my zsh discovery process.

Comment: This is especially helpful for python programmers who use zsh. I call my virtualenvs `venv` and when I want to activate them I tend to not start the path to `activate` script with `.`, and when I want to tab complete `venv` folder in the cwd, so many options in the PATH will pop-up. Took me really long time to find this answer. Thanks!