# How to limit ZSH autocomplete to the current directory

Tags: tabs, zsh, completion

I'm having a base zsh + oh-my-zsh install on a WSL2 Ubuntu. Zsh's autocomplete system (maybe coupled with oh-my-zsh's setup) by default completes anything from a path lookup, so when I'm in a folder, and I type a few letters, it annoyingly gives me a list of all unrelated .dll files, instead of completing to a subfolder from the *current directory*.

I've read different answers from stackoverflow, none of it worked. I asked ChatGPT ;), which gave me this:

`zstyle ':completion:*' file-patterns './**'`

which didn't work either.

Comment: Do you need to change this for just a small set of commands? If so, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72710684/9307265) may help.

Comment: @Gairfowl No, I want it to work this way globally, even when I'm not using the "cd" command, just typing + tab. I never want to see files from the PATH.